# Associação has_many through [RAILS 3.2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modelo-relacional, tablemodel

Estou tendo problema com uma associação `has_many`, `through` em um projeto que estou trabalhando.

No caso eu preciso modelar uma relação que adiciona o atributo ordem a tabela de relação.

Para tentar modelar a relação procurei um [guia na versão 3.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association) do rails, pois utilizamos esta versão devido a alguns problemas de adaptação.

Tentei implementar para testar a associação, como no exemplo, mas **sempre que tento relacionar os modelos ele não insere a relação na tabela**. Meu código ficou assim:

```
class Medico < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nome

  has_many :consultas
  has_many :pacientes, through: :consultas
end


class Paciente < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nome

  has_many :consultas
  has_many :medicos, through: :consultas
end
```

E:

```
class Consulta < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :medico
  belongs_to :paciente

  attr_accessible :ordem
end
```

As migrates também foram geradas automaticamente e ficaram assim:

```
class CreateMedicos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :medicos do |t|
      t.string :nome

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreatePacientes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pacientes do |t|
      t.string :nome

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateConsulta < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :consulta do |t|
      t.references :medico
      t.references :paciente
      t.integer :ordem

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :consulta, :medico_id
    add_index :consulta, :paciente_id
  end
end
```

Acontece que quando vou criar um médico e criar um paciente associando a um médico, **ele não da o `INSERT` na tabela consulta**, por exemplo:

```
m1 = Medico.create(nome:"Dr. Medico") (0.4ms)  
BEGIN
  SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO "medicos" ("created_at", "nome", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 07 Dec 2018 17:28:15 -02 -02:00], ["nome", "Dr. Medico"], ["updated_at", Fri, 07 Dec 2018 17:28:15 -02 -02:00]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Medico id: 10, nome: "Dr. Medico", created_at: "2018-12-07 19:28:15", updated_at: "2018-12-07 19:28:15">
```

p1 = Paciente.create(nome:"Paciente 1", medicos: [m1])

```
BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "medicos" ("created_at", "nome", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 07 Dec 2018 17:28:47 -02 -02:00], ["nome", "Dr. Medico"], ["updated_at", Fri, 07 Dec 2018 17:28:47 -02 -02:00]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Medico id: 11, nome: "Dr. Medico", created_at: "2018-12-07 19:28:47", updated_at: "2018-12-07 19:28:47">
```

Observação: Esta é minha primeira publicação no stack, sou inciante na área de desenvolvimento, então peço desculpa desde já caso tenha ficado confuso. :)

Answer (score 3):

Olá, em ruby temos uma forma mais expressiva de adicionar itens em um array.

#### podemos usar *<<*

Aqui por mais que usemos o `new` ele vai salvar o objeto quando adicionado a  um array.

```
medico = Medico.create(nome:"Dr. Medico")
medico.consultas << Paciente.new(nome:"Paciente 1")
```

#### ou o collection.create()

Essa outra forma é legal pois você tá está na collection e pede pra adicionar mais um usando o `create`.

```
medico = Medico.create(nome:"Dr. Medico")
medico.consultas.create(nome:"Paciente 1")
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder :)

Tentei realizar a operação, mas continua dando erro, porém agora um erro diferente. 



ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Consulta(#47218530709060) expected, got Paciente(#47218527660420) from usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-. 2.22.5/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:210:in `raise_on_type_mismatch'

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver só explicitando nos modelos o attr_accessible referenciando o outro modelo, acredito que isso seja uma limitação devido a versão que estamos utilizando.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo @jfranca